# Svelte - how to use methods in template?

Tags: svelte

With vue I was usually extractiog any complex logic into methods eg

```
<li v-for="todo in todos" v-show="!isTodoComplete(todo)">
  {{ todo }}
</li>
```

But when I'm trying the same approach with svelte:

```
{#each todos as todo}
    <li hidden={isComplete(todo)}>{todo}</li>
{/each}
...
methods: { isComplete (todo) { ... } }
```

I'm getting error `TypeError: ctx.isComplete is not a function`.

Am I doing something wrong? How to do such things sveltes way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Svelte distinguishes between [helpers](https://svelte.technology/guide#helpers) and [methods](https://svelte.technology/guide#custom-methods).

**Helpers** are functions used inside your template to process data — they should be pure functions, and don't have access to component state except what is passed in as an argument (such as the `todo` object).

**Methods** are functions that *do* things, often in response to an event. They do have access to component state.

In this case, `isComplete` should be a helper, not a method.

Comment: Thanks Rich, helpers looks more like vues filters for me. Was it intentional decision to make them stateless or it was hard to get them access to state? Maybe there is any doc / article I can read?

Comment: It's intentional. Unlike with methods, you have no control over *when* the function gets run — it just runs as often as necessary to stay up to date — and so it's important that those functions don't have side effects. Docs here https://svelte.technology/guide#helpers